# Finding the High-Level and Low-Level modules in dependencies for applying Dependency Inversion Principe

Tags: design-patterns, dependencies, dependency-inversion

The [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) say:

- High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both
  should depend on abstractions.
- Abstractions should not depend upon    details. Details should depend
  upon abstractions.

How can I practically find the *High-level* and the *Low-level* modules in my applications, is there any clear definition for them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how usually I refer them:

**High Level Module** --> this module represent more business aspect rather than technical aspect.  It can be refered as an abstraction rather than implementation, and usually achieved through interfaces.

Some example maybe: `RegisterAccount`, `PostAnswer`, `PostQuestion`, `AddComment`, `InsertComment`.

Since **Low Level Module** represent more technical aspect rather than the business aspect. Say for example we take the `InsertComment` HLM. The LLM should be:

1. Open database connection
2. Execute insert statement
3. Close database connection

A High Level Module can be a Low Level Module in another context. Taking another example, `AddComment`'s LLM should be:

1. Validate the comment (e.g. 15 char min) --> this will be another HLM
2. Insert comment to database --> this will be another HLM (`InsertComment`)
3. Add notification to involved user --> this will be another HLM

The same apply for other HLM as well.